# Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function | when trying to pass in parameter from App.js to Solidity

Tags: solidity, json-rpc

I am trying to call a function in my Solidity file (Coder.sol), while passing through a parameter from my App.js file. My function in my App.js file looks like this:

```
handleStartRequirement: function(reqId, payment_amount) {

  var coderInstance;
  App.web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
    // Set client address equal to a testrpc account
    let client = accounts[0];
    App.contracts.Coder.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      coderInstance = instance;
      const thing =  coderInstance.startRequirement.call().then(res => {
        return coderInstance.startRequirement(payment_amount, {from: client, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }).then(function(success) {
      App.markReadytoStart(reqId);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    });
  },
```

The startRequirement function in my Solidity file looks like this:

`function startRequirement(address _client, uint256 _contract_amount) returns (bool) {
      client = _client;
      return true;
  }`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I am getting the following error every time:

> Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

I am declaring the following variables in my Solidity file:

> address public client;         //ETH wallet address for the client
>
> int contract_amount;

The parameters would be getting transferred via the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, the issue was that my .sol file was not able to take in an integer parameter from my App.js file. The way I solved this was to simply remigrate with the command:

> truffle migrate --reset

The previous block that my contract was sitting on may have just been corrupt with code, so migrating all my .sol files to a new block solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have this error because you provide only one argument instead two(as declared in the contract) in this line:

```
coderInstance.startRequirement(payment_amount,{from: client, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

you need to provide an address try

```
coderInstance.startRequirement(payment_amount,eth.acccounts[0],{from: client, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `startRequirement` twice from Javascript. In each case you have to give it the 2 parameters it expects:

```
//                                                !!Here!!
const thing = coderInstance.startRequirement.call(to_whom, payment_amount).then(res => {
//                                        !!And here!!
    return coderInstance.startRequirement(to_whom, payment_amount, {from: client, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
})
```